# How to stop Snow Leopard from prompting me to upgrade to El Capitan?

Tags: snow-leopard, macos

I have a 2008 MacBook with Snow Leopard on it.

I don't want to upgrade to newer OS versions.

Snow Leopard keeps prompting me to upgrade to El Capitan.

Is there any way to get it to stop this permanently?

Comment: Disable software updates.

Comment: @JohnKeates That doesn't work. I have "Check for updates" unchecked, but it still occasionally nags me about upgrading to El Cap. I'm running Snow Leopard under VirtualBox on an El Cap machine, I don't need to upgrade the VM.

Comment: In what manner does it prompt you? Is it via the AppStore, via a notification popup or some other means?